# How to clearly separate ui and business logic in an iOS/Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, architecture

I'm relatively new to iOS development but have significant experience in Android/Java/Kotlin. So I tend to structure my ios projects a bit similar to my Android ones. So the basic structure I use is

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
  private let viewModel = ViewModel()
} 

class ViewModel{
  func doSomethingAsync(delegate){
    SomeFactory.createService().doSomethingAsync(){
      delegate.callback
    }
  }
}

class SomeFactory{
  static func createService() -> Service {return ServiceImpl()}
}

class Service{
  func doSomething()
}

class ServiceImpl : Service{
  func doSomething(){... implementation...}
}
```

So the view controller doesn't know anything about the business logic or services and all it sees are data models. The view model provides the bridging between the two. Also, no one can see the `ServiceImpl` class and is only accessible via the factory. Is this design over the top or is it too "javaish" for ios? How do people usually separate their view logic with the service/business logic of an app?

Comment: In answer to the "pull business logic out of view controller", yes we frequently do that. It's a matter of personal preference whether you achieve this with MVP, MVVM, or some other pattern. The factory pattern is less common, though.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the typo fixes (its quite late over here). This pattern is a slightly modified version of the Abstract Factory Pattern which is common in Java. I use the factory class because its the one place that defines all the service classes - ie: the view model's gateway to all the services.

Comment: I’m familiar w the pattern, but I merely suggest that it’s less common. You asked us whether your above was overkill, and I suggest that view models often can be useful, but abstract factories less frequently so (or, at least if your concern was just separation of view and business logic).

Comment: I see. So you would usually go with a 'controller -> model -> service' design without using the factory?

Answer (score 1):

In `viewController`
Update your UI elements.

With out ui element updation everything’s (business logics) surely move to `viewModel`

Comment: do you keep all your REST service stuff also in the viewModel?

Comment: Yes, api callings are in viewModel

Comment: say you have two api service classes with the same interface but different implementation. How would you switch between the two using a compiler flag (ie: you want to use one or the other depending on the ios target) ? You'd have to check every time you use the service class in a view model, yes?

Comment: I have implemented a separate class for api data downloading. Each functions with completion handlers. So, easily I will call a function where every i need i will call and get a response data.

Comment: You're not answering my question, mate. How do you handle multiple implementations of an api class based on the app target?